# go to a specific slide in jquery html slider unslider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to go to a specific slide in the jquery HTML slider unslider.

The solution I found on the web does not work.

I am calling the specific slide, but it does not load. it does nothing.
what am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wohnungsslider').unslider({
    autoplay: false,
    nav: true,
    arrows: {
      prev: '<a class="' + self._ + '-arrow prev">z</a>',
      next: '<a class="' + self._ + '-arrow next">v</a>'
    }
  });
});
$("#somelink").click(function() {
  $('.wohnungsslider').unslider('animate:1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/js/unslider-min.js" integrity="sha512-mGetBI3EloHb9QY+HpWMJz+ca+gaJB5MnbFm3SqEujV56YyQMoxI8V5GkZvQsHz/srjXrUSLzyz547fTCy0B3A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Titel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/css/unslider.css" integrity="sha512-eVNawD6ZqjO6kncfu+QGDPgMEjED+6bVs7nkO/VXJhCCprDG5VC+A0Jchcuri63WQGi6pUFCRI+J0GLuzRJtFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/css/unslider-dots.css" integrity="sha512-0y9RGi5Bzc42lPRcR/CJVv06oRYqtDuTmwfshZ/gxxytGGbij30UblI1dzw3wkT2KxTNcImqmXR7v3xJUQGf9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wohnungsuebersicht">
    <a href="#" onclick="$('.wohnungsslider').unslider('animate:0');">test</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('.wohnungsslider').unslider('animate:1');">test2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('.wohnungsslider').unslider('animate:2');">test3</a>
    <a href="#" id="somelink">asdf</a>
  </div>
  <div class="wohnungsslider">
    <ul>
      <li>slide 1</li>
      <li>slide 2</li>
      <li>slide 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have created the code snippet for your give code can you explain what exactly not working?

Comment: thank you very much! did you use the same code? in my version the slide does not load, when the link is clicked. in your snippet it does work.

Comment: In that case, check the console for errors.

Comment: that is the problem, there is no error message in the console

Comment: @wmarx Maybe the JS files you are using are not loading properly(or there Paths might be having some issue) try replacing them with the CDN, as mentioned in the code snippet.

Comment: Great. I use the CDN now and now it works.